# Angular 2 RXJS filter result if contains a string

Tags: angular, rxjs, indexof

How to filter results ?

I make a call to an endpoint, and receive data in the next form:

```
{"children":["Folder1/Data1","Folder1/Data2","Folder1/Data3","Folder1/Data4","Folder1/Value_1","Folder1/Value_2"],"path":"Folder1/Data","type":"Folder"}
```

I want to filter the results by obtaining only the children items that contain the word Value, for example: `"Folder1/Value_1" and "Folder1/Value_2"`

So far I have the next:

I subscribe to this service from my component

```
public recorders: Model[];

  getValues() {
    this._service.getValues().subscribe(
      values => { console.log(values) },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
```

Service:

```
  getValues(): Observable<Model[]> {
    let url = "some url";
    let subString = 'Value';
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .filter((body) => body.includes(subString))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response, item) {
    let body = res.json().children;    
    return body;
  }


  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); 
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

I also tried :

```
  .filter((body) => { return (body.indexOf("Value") === -1) }) or
  .map(data => data.filter(data => data.indexOf('Value') === -1))
```

but it didn´t work, and by that I mean that console.log inside the subscribe doesn´t print anything at all, however I can print all the results if I write a console.log inside "map" (extractData method).

At the end, I want to get the "children" which contain the string "Value" because I want to make a new http call to each one of them (by combining them with a url)
for example "some url"/Value_1  , but that´s another story.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your last line should work. Try `includes`: `.map(data => data.filter(name => name.includes('Value')))`

Comment: @jhhoff02 It works! silly me.

Comment: Nice! Did you end up using `includes` or `indexOf`?

Comment: @jhhoff02 includes, I haven´t managed to get it work with indexOf, either it throws an error saying it is not possible to use it with the type of data variable, or it just doesn´t do anything at all.

Comment: Interesting, I think you're supposed to be able to use `indexOf` on strings but it's probably expecting an array

Comment: Well the http get returns an array of values from "children" , but I also tried to use indexOf in "extractData" without success.